# Access denied error while uploading a file in Selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, ui-automation

I am running my automation scripts in a remote desktop. When I come out of the remote machine and work on my local, file uploads to the application are failing with access denied error. I have observed that when user is not on the remote machine, SendWait method is not passing the file path into the file explorer window which is opened by the browser. Below is the selenium c# code for file uploads.

```
        SendKeys.SendWait(@"" + filePath);
        Thread.Sleep(3000); 
        SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
```

I used below AutoIt code too. Still file path is not inserted in the file explorer window which is opened by the browser after clicking on upload file button when I come out of the remote machine.
Issue is not seen and file path is inserted into file when the user is on the remote machine

```
        AutoItX.ControlEnable("Open","", "ComboBox1");
        AutoItX.ControlFocus("Open", "", "ComboBox1");
        AutoItX.ControlEnable("Open", "", "Edit1");
        AutoItX.ControlSetText("Open", "", "Edit1",filePath);
        AutoItX.ControlEnable("Open", "", "Button1");
        AutoItX.ControlClick("Open", "", "Button1");
```

User has full permissions to the folder too. Seeing access denied error in the automation report at file uploads.